# PUT or POST on the Google-Worflows and Google-Admin

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workflows

I am integrating a project in GCP-Workflows with GCP-Admin, but I am having difficulty entering data in the Admin (I intend to set the field "" suspended ": true / false}). But the GCP-Admin accepts only the PUT and not POST, I checked in the Playground, since the GCP-Workflows does not have the PUT method, how to get around the situation?

Answer (score 0):

According to [GCP Workflows documentation](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax?authuser=3#invoking_an_http_endpoint), you can use next step for doing any type of HTTP request `GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH`.

So for `PUT` it will look that way:

```yaml
- STEP_NAME:
    call: http.request
    args:
        url: URL_VALUE
        method: PUT
        headers:
            KEY:VALUE
        body:
            KEY:VALUE
        query:
            KEY:VALUE
        auth:
            type:{OIDC|OAuth2}
        timeout: VALUE_IN_SECONDS
    result: RESPONSE_VARIABLE
```